# How to use BatchNormalization3D in chainer?

Tags: chainer

Is chainer.links.BatchNormalization can only support 2D feature map ? How to write BatchNormalization3D code in chainer?

Furthermore, pytorch has already support the BN3D here:
https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=batchnorm3d#torch.nn.BatchNorm3d
it is 5D input (a mini-batch of 3D inputs with additional channel dimension)

Answer (score 0):

Chainer is going to support this feature in the next release (v5.0.0b1).
Please see the discussion [here](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/4753).